# surge_confirmation_id changes between requests

Tags: uber-api

I am making two requests to the Uber API in a row.

`POST /v1/requests/estimate`

`POST /v1/requests`

The first to get an estimate and the second to make the ride request. When I get the estimate I am getting a value for `surge_confirmation_id`. I send this value as a parameter of the same name when making the request to the API for creating a ride request.

The response from Uber on the second request is a 409 error, saying that there is surge pricing in effect and providing me with a different `surge_confirmation_id` than what was provided in the estimate.

I have run this test about 7 times and the `surge_confirmation_id` is always different between the first and second request. Any idea what I am doing wrong, or whether this is expected behavior? It doesn't make sense that the surge estimate would always be wrong or change so quickly (we are talking 5 seconds between the two requests).

Side note, the `/v1/requests/estimate` endpoint is the only endpoint which returns the surge multiplier as a number. Calling `/v1/requests` will only return a URL to show the surge confirmation. This is not acceptable for me because I am coding a voice-based service which does not allow me to show any UI.

Answer (score 1):

`Estimates` is only for you to estimate the price and trip.

You should present the received url by some ways since the url would load a website for customer to accept or deny the surge price.

Once customer accepts it then you can pass the `surge_confirmation_id` back to Uber.